# Angular table *ngIf="userDetails" class="table-fill" not displayed

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

There's my problem.
On my app, on my userprofile i have to display users info.

For this :

This is my user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user.model';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User = {
    fullName: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
 };

noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True'}) };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

//httpMethods

postUser(user: User){
return this.http.post( 
environment.apiBaseUrl+'/register',user,this.noAuthHeader);
}

login(authCredentials: any){
  return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/authenticate', 
   authCredentials, this.noAuthHeader);
}

getUserProfile(){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/userProfile');
} // need jwt in header

//Helper Methods

setToken(token: string) {

  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}

getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

deleteToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
}

getUserPayload(){
  var token = this.getToken();
  if (token) {
    var getUserPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
    return JSON.parse(getUserPayload);
  }
  else
  return null;
}

isLoggedIn() {
  var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
  if (userPayload)
    return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
  else
    return false;
}
}
```

here is my user-profile.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
selector: 'app-user-profile',
templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
 export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 userDetails;
 constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.userDetails = res['user'];
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);}
 );
}

onLogout(){
  this.userService.deleteToken();
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}

}
```

and here is my user-profile.component.html

```
<table *ngIf="userDetails" class="table-fill">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <th colspan="2" class="text-center">User Profile</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>{{userDetails.fullName.split(' ')[0]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>{{userDetails.fullName.split(' ')[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>{{userDetails.email}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
          <input type="button" (click)="onLogout()" value="Logout" />
      </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

When i'm logged nothing is displayed. I think the error come frome my ngOnInit .. but i don't find solutions.

Comment: Have you tried logging `res` in your subscription? I'd be interested in what you're getting back (if anything). It should help answer your question. `(res) => { console.log(res);
    this.userDetails = res['user'];
  },`

Comment: i ve tried 
     ngOnInit() {
      this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.userDetails = res['user'];
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);}
    );
  }


I have nothing in my console. (maybe this is not the correct place for the console.log i'm pretty new on this framework

Comment: Try to network the userProfile request in devtools. Can you see the response API data?

Comment: i found where was the issue. In my authGuard, i've had one wrong line : this.userService.deleteToken();  . After being connected, token was deleted that's why my form ain't displayed. :)